# Private fields vs Properties in constructors

Tags: c#

I'm wondering whether there's any significant performance (or correctness) difference in using private fields in class constructors, instead of Properties that change those private fields.

Sample:

```
class Pt<T>
{
    public Pt(T _x, T _y)   // More efficient/correct?
    {
        this.x = _x;    // or x = _x
        this.y = _y;    // or y = _y
    }

    public Pt(T _x, T _y)   // Less efficient/correct?
    {
        X = _x;
        Y = _y;
    }

    private T x, y;

    T X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
    T Y { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }
}
```

Comment: There will be a big difference in correctness if the properties perform an additional action (log the new value, raise a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event, or simlar)...

Comment: This will help you understand it better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17578356/3365113

Comment: Properties tend to serialise 'better' than fields. For `private` variables that is rarely a concern, so it doesn't matter much either way.

Comment: Only if the property setter performs some logic. Remember, the whole point of a property is to control how a field is exposed outside of your class - inside the type, without custom logic in your getters and setters, that's not a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of correctness, there is absolutely no difference in your code. From a performance point of view, there is a slight overhead when using the property version, because setting/getting a property requires an additional method call, because properties are translated to methods by the compiler. This performance hit is so minor it will not be noticeable, so **write the version which is most readable and consistent with .NET standards**.